# Will Ubuntu 16.04 run Unity 8 on the desktop?

Tags: unity, mir, 16.04, unity8

Will Ubuntu 16.04 run Unity 8 by default?

Softpedia mentions that it'll probably be for 16.10...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it will not be using Unity 8, the default will remain Unity 7 & Compiz

This video indicates that the Unity 8 team is targetting 16.10:

- https://youtu.be/Clf4Dvy-x4w?t=42m10s

Comment: Please provide your source(s).

Comment: @ParanoidPanda softpedia according to the question :+

Comment: @Rinzwind: Yes, nevertheless it is a good practice to provide sources for claims made in answers (as well as questions of course - a link would be nice).