# Is the ZFS 100% sure will be in Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: zfs, 16.04

Some people on reddit say that it may not be in 16.04, will it?

I have lost lots of data on XFS, so I am looking foward to the ZFS.

Comment: Partial dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/740470/will-ubuntu-16-04-run-unity-8-on-the-desktop

Comment: As for ZFS, that's the intention: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/02/zfs-is-fs-for-containers-in-ubuntu-1604.html

Comment: So it will be the default file system when installing Ubuntu? What does baked mean?

Comment: AFAIK that's still going to be ext4. ZFS will be the default for containers.

Comment: What is the container? Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC, http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd

Comment: Made it zfs only ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is there in my system:

```
$ locate zfs
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zfs.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zfscrypt.mod
/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/zfsinfo.mod
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/avl
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/nvpair
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/spl
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/splat
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/unicode
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/zcommon
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/zpios
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/avl/zavl.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/nvpair/znvpair.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/spl/spl.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/splat/splat.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/unicode/zunicode.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/zcommon/zcommon.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-10-generic/kernel/zfs/zpios/zpios.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/avl
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/nvpair
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/spl
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/splat
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/unicode
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/zcommon
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/zpios
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/avl/zavl.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/nvpair/znvpair.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/spl/spl.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/splat/splat.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/unicode/zunicode.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/zcommon/zcommon.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
/lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic/kernel/zfs/zpios/zpios.ko
/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/zfs.mod
...
```

It is a filesystem for [containers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS) ([LXC, LinuX Containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC)) so not for the operating system itself. "ext4" will be the filesystem for Ubuntu at least for the next few years.

I can not pick it in gParted (well at least not yet):

[image]

Comment: Considering it combines LVM/RAID/traditional filesystem roles, ZFS is a lot more than a "filesystem for containers". Ubuntu only chooses to make it the default for containers.

Comment: Yes I know. Was checking out gparted to see if it can be added there :D But looks like that is not the way to use it :-P It has its own management tools.

Comment: It's coming, slowly: http://gparted.org/news.php?item=193